.NET9 MAUI Hybrid with Web App - Using appsettings.json
I'm looking to create a solution with MAUI clients (Windows, Android, iOS) and a Wasm Client (hosted).
Additionally I will deploy a Web API, which will be consumed by the MAUI Clients and the Wasm clients.
The base url of the Web API will depend on the environment (Dev, Test, Prod).
In the Wasm client, I can use appsettings.json, appsettings.Development.json, and appsettings.Production.json to provide the base url used by the Wasm client.
I can just use:
builder.Services.Configure<MyOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MyOptions"))

which will load the section from the appropriate appsettings file automatically based on current environment.
How can I achieve the same flexibility in the MAUI client?

You can also use the appsettings.json in the MAUI Blazor, appsettings have to be embedded resource (rightclick on appsettings.json > properties > Build Action > embedded resource).

Thanks @GuangyuBai-MSFT.  However, the ASPNet appsettings file will be chosen based on ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT, but this is not available in MAUI.  Have simulated this by using conditional compile logic based on Debug vs Release configuration to select the file.  I guess if I needed additional appsettings files for, say, release deployment to a pre-prod environment then I'd need to set up a Release-PreProd configuration so that my conditional compile logic can be sensitive to this and load up the correct appsettings file.
